# Wrong parsing url - index.htm/index instead of index/index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-server

I've installed Zend Server CE on Lubuntu. On Zend Server CE on Windows, and also on my hosting everything works fine.

my **public/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I'm trying to go into:

> /project/public/index/index/menu/Gallery/type/2

it shows me an error:

> The requested URL /project/public/index.htm/index/menu/Gallery/type/2
>   was not found on this server.

**Why id adds me .htm to index?**

For example /project/public/admin or  project/public/index/edit/id/16 works fine.

PS. 
Index- controller
index- action
menu - action

Can you give me an quick-link about formating urls in Zend, becouse I don't know why i.e. index/menu doesn't work on windows instead of index/index/menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Zend MVC application, take a look on this

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

If you're using modules then default routing should be

> /module/controller/action/param1name/param1value

or if you don't use modules just

> /controller/action/param1name/param1value

if there are not all params provided, index is default controller and action name